# first instance of retrieveing a value with jquery is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i am trying to retrieve each message id with jquery, but for the first instance of the messages that the user has, the message id is not retrieved and is undefined, but for all other messages it is working fine.

```js
var mssg_id = $(this).find('input[name="fav"]').val(); // this is what i am doing to retrieve the messages id
```

below is my jquery code:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.favourite-form', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent a normal postback and allow ajax to run instead
  var mssg_id = $(this).find('input[name="fav"]').val();
  $.ajax({ 
    data: mssg_id, 
    type: "post", 
    url: "favorite.php?message="+mssg_id, 
    success: function(data) { 
      alert("Data Save: " + mssg_id); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { //gracefully handle any errors in the UI
      alert("An ajax error occurred: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
  }); 
});
```

HTML

```js
<form class="favourite-form" name="favform" method="POST" >
  <input type="submit" name="fav"  value="<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>" />
</form>
```

What is causing the first instance of the messages value to be undefined?

Comment: Check the markup. [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) only returns `undefined` when there's no element in the collection.

Comment: check the image attached, there is a value and an element but it is still being undefined,

Comment: Please show the code of first and second messages as well from elements tab

Comment: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question**. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane i added all the images aboe

Comment: Okay, which one is the first one ... upper one or latter one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, from your image you provided. I figured out that you have `favourite-form` which does not contain any of the content in the upper part of your code. So, it was returning undefined. While, lower div is perfect as you should be expecting as input was inside the form.

This line `var mssg_id = $(this).find('input[name="fav"]').val();` take the id from the form's `input` but it input is outside of form, so you were getting issue.

*Note:- Please use codes rather than using image as mentioned in [Best way to ask answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: youre correct the first message is outside of the form for some reason, i am trying to understand why and try to fix it. i only included images in this question because i believed it was necessary to see whats going on to understand the problem, but thank u i will not post images again

Comment: Great... okay then how are you rendering muliple messages. Is the first one intially there? You have to show how are you creating each messages in order to find the main problem.

Comment: these messages are coming from the database for each user when he receives a message from another user. i dont understand why the form is not being printed correctly for the first message only.

Comment: found the issue, it was very minor, a table tag that was un needed, its working fine now. but thank you so much for understanding where the problem is!!!!